# php query is not adding all data to jsonarray

Tags: php, mysql

i am new to PHP OOP , i have a database that contains products, the goal is to extract for every product grouped by ligne field all the months data of the products, after i executed the result i have been surprised that only the data of the month 8 is displayed while there are some products that have data in months like 4 or 6.

Here the database rows:

[image]

Here the json Result array and we can observe that some products qte in some months is displayed as zero while their qte is not zero in some cases

```
[
    {
        "id": "8",
        "ligne": "Biscuit",
        "produit": "Major",
        "date": "2021-08-11",
        "heure": "10:00",
        "qte": "380",
        "months": [
            {
                "month": 1,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 2,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 3,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 4,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 5,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 6,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 7,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 8,
                "qte": 380
            },
            {
                "month": 9,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 10,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 11,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 12,
                "qte": 0
            }
        ],
        "year": "2021"
    },
    {
        "id": "6",
        "ligne": "Eau",
        "produit": "Safia 1.5",
        "date": "2021-08-11",
        "heure": "14:00",
        "qte": "320",
        "months": [
            {
                "month": 1,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 2,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 3,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 4,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 5,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 6,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 7,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 8,
                "qte": 320
            },
            {
                "month": 9,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 10,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 11,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 12,
                "qte": 0
            }
        ],
        "year": "2021"
    },
    {
        "id": "12",
        "ligne": "Lait",
        "produit": "Vitalait 1/2",
        "date": "2021-08-11",
        "heure": "8:00",
        "qte": "379",
        "months": [
            {
                "month": 1,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 2,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 3,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 4,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 5,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 6,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 7,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 8,
                "qte": 379
            },
            {
                "month": 9,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 10,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 11,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 12,
                "qte": 0
            }
        ],
        "year": "2021"
    },
    {
        "id": "10",
        "ligne": "Salami",
        "produit": "Mazraa",
        "date": "2021-08-11",
        "heure": "8:00",
        "qte": "570",
        "months": [
            {
                "month": 1,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 2,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 3,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 4,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 5,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 6,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 7,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 8,
                "qte": 570
            },
            {
                "month": 9,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 10,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 11,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 12,
                "qte": 0
            }
        ],
        "year": "2021"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "ligne": "Yaourt",
        "produit": "Delice",
        "date": "2021-08-11",
        "heure": "12:00",
        "qte": "1020",
        "months": [
            {
                "month": 1,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 2,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 3,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 4,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 5,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 6,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 7,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 8,
                "qte": 1020
            },
            {
                "month": 9,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 10,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 11,
                "qte": 0
            },
            {
                "month": 12,
                "qte": 0
            }
        ],
        "year": "2021"
    }
]
```

Here the Php Code :

```
   public function getProductsStatsByMonths() {
    $today =  date("Y-m-d"); 
    $date_arr = explode("-", $today);  
    $year = $date_arr[0];
    $month = $date_arr[1];
    $day = $date_arr[2];
 
    $prods = array();
    $months = array(
    1 ,
    2 ,
    3 ,
    4 ,
    5 ,
    6 ,
    7 ,
    8 ,
    9 ,
    10 ,
    11 ,
    12
 );


        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT SUM(qte) as total , id ,ligne, produit, date, heure FROM production where YEAR(date) = ?  GROUP BY LOWER(ligne) ");
        $stmt->execute([$year]);
       
    while( $row = $stmt->fetch(pdo::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $date_arrrow = explode("-", $row["date"]);  
        $rowmonth = $date_arrrow[1];
        $ligne = $row["ligne"];
        $produit = $row["produit"];
        $p = new ProductionByMonth($row["id"],$row["ligne"],$row["produit"],$row["date"],$row["heure"],$row["total"],-1,$year);
        $prodmonths = array();
    foreach ($months as $month){
       
        if(($rowmonth == $month) ){
            array_push($prodmonths,new Months($month,(int) $row["total"]));
            // array_push($prods, new ProductionByMonth($row["id"],$row["ligne"],$row["produit"],$row["date"],$row["heure"],$row["total"],$month,$year));
         }else if ($rowmonth != $month){
            array_push($prodmonths,new Months($month,0));
            // array_push($prods, new ProductionByMonth($row["id"],$row["ligne"],$row["produit"],$row["date"],$row["heure"],0,$month,$year));  
          }
            
        }
    $p->months = $prodmonths;
    array_push($prods,$p);
    
    }
   

    echo json_encode($prods);   


   }
```

My wish is to find a way to correctly extract all the correct qte in the json array for every product grouped by ligne field

Comment: can you highlight which product is incorrect? the first one IS correct...

Comment: for example the product with id 18 with ligne = Yaourt

Comment: can you post the data in a table so it can easily be copied?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend grouping and aggregating the data entirely in the application. `$grp` is the core data structure. However, it needs a second pass for aggregation. Performance-wise, this is okay, as it is O(n).

I created a live example at http://road-to-eng.rlc.ninja/. I also  recommend separating the aggregation logic from the presentation logic (unlike my implementation).

Here's the code:

```
<?php
// DB LOGIC
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=<redacted>;dbname=<redacted>", "<redacted>", "<redacted>");

$flig = $_POST["ligne"];

if (isset($flig) && $flig != "all") {
    $sql = "select * from orders where ligne = ?;";
    $params = [$flig];
} else {
    $sql = "select * from orders;";
    $params = [];
}

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($params);
$res = $stmt->fetchAll();

// GROUPING LOGIC
$lignes = [];
$grp = [];
foreach ($res as $ord) {
    $mo = (int) substr($ord["date"], 5, 2);
    $ligne = $ord["ligne"];
    $lignes[$ligne] = null;

    if (!isset($grp[$ligne])) {
        $grp[$ligne] = [];
    }

    if (!isset($grp[$ligne][$mo])) {
        $grp[$ligne][$mo] = [];
    }

    array_push($grp[$ligne][$mo], $ord);
}
$lignes = array_keys($lignes);
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="ligne">
                    <option value="all" selected>-- all --</option>
<?php foreach ($lignes as $l) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $l ?>"><?php echo $l ?></option>
<?php } ?>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<pre>
<?php
// PRESENTATION AND AGGREGATION LOGIC (tightly coupled, not good practice)
printf("<strong>YEAR %s</strong>\n", "2021");
printf("\n");
foreach ($grp as $ligne => $ords_of_mo) {
    printf("%s\n", $ligne);
    foreach ($ords_of_mo as $mo => $ords) {
        printf("\t%s\n", date("M", mktime(0, 0, 0, $mo+1, 0, 0)));

        // AGGREGATION LOGIC
        $tot_qte = 0;
        foreach ($ords as $o) {
            $tot_qte += $o["qte"];
        }

        printf("\t\t%5s %10s %15s %15s %12s %10s\n", "id", "ligne", "produit", "date", "heure", "qte");
        printf("\t\t========================================================================\n");
        foreach ($ords as $o) {
            printf("\t\t%5s %10s %15s %15s %12s %10s\n", $o["id"], $o["ligne"], $o["produit"], $o["date"], $o["heure"], $o["qte"]);
        }
        printf("\t\t%5s %10s %15s %15s %12s <strong>%10s</strong>\n", "", "", "", "", "", $tot_qte);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
?>
</pre>
```